# Match Column A and B and return column C in same row as column B

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create and array formula that fill entire column C, and checks if cell from column A exists in column B then return value in column B in same row line.
PS: Column A has only first and last name, column b has full name, if column b contains column a then return b in same row line.

Sheet2:
[Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=1682305544)

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Your goal is not clear, either in your post or in your spreadsheet. Please *hand-enter* in the spreadsheet the results you want a formula to produce in the same place you want the formula to be. Then let us know where to look for those hand-entered results.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try this:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2=B2,B2,""))

This will fill up C if A is matching in B and returns column B in C:

[image]